# I am working on ES for the first time. I am trying to upload a bulk json file into a new Elasticsearch index in java but I am getting errors

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, mapping, bulk

I am creating a new index and then mapping the json data

```
        CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("demoreport");
        request.mapping(
            "{\n" +
                    "      \"properties\": {\n" +
                    "        \"Identifier code\": {\n" +
                    "          \"type\": \"char(3)\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        \"User ID\": {\n" +
                    "          \"type\": \"char(38)\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "      }\n" +
                    "}",XContentType.JSON);
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/demoreport/_doc/5");
```

My JSON File:

```
[
{
    "IDENTIFIER_CD": "PT ",
    "USER_ID": "123458 
}
{
    "IDENTIFIER_CD": "SR ",
    "USER_ID": "12345678  
}
]
```

I am getting error as :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapping source must be pairs of fieldnames and properties definition.

here is the complete code : Here I am trying to post the Json file generated from the database to elasticsearch server.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.CreateIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
public class MyScheduler {
public static void send() {
    CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("kibanareport");
    request.settings(Settings.builder()
            .put("index.number_of_shards", 20)
            .put("index.number_of_replicas", 10)
    );
    request.mapping(
            "{\n" +
                    "      \"properties\": {\n" +
                    "        \"user_ID\": {\n" +
                    "          \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        \"doc_ID\": {\n" +
                    "          \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "      }\n" +
                    "}", XContentType.JSON);
    Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<>();
    message.put("type", "text");
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("message", message);
    Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    mapping.put("properties", properties);
    XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
    builder.startObject();
    {
        builder.startObject("properties");
        {
            builder.startObject("message");
            {
                builder.field("type", "text");
            }
            builder.endObject();
        }
        builder.endObject();
    }
    builder.endObject();
    String fileName = "downloads/JSONFile.json";
    File jsonFile = new File(fileName);
    HttpEntity entity = new FileEntity(jsonFile);
    HttpPost post = new
            HttpPost("http://localhost:9200/kibanareport/_doc");
    post.setEntity(entity);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response: " + response);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatype char(3) that you have used in your `CreateIndexRequest` is wrong. 
Please refer to this Elasticsearch docs for field datatype supported by Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html

Currently for your mapping I have used `text` datatype for your `Identifier code` since it is string and `Integer` for `User ID` field. You can change as per your requirements.

Here , is the updated `CreateIndexRequest` :

```
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("demoreport");
    request.mapping(
                "{\n" +
                "      \"properties\": {\n" +
                "        \"Identifier code\": {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        \"User ID\": {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"integer\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "}",XContentType.JSON);
```

Comment: @aka_GK Can I know specifically in the code where this error came and how you are creating this new index by using ESRestHighlevelclient or something else ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting datatype error, but I'm still getting the same error. The error is coming in request.mapping line specifically.

Comment: Can you post the complete code.Regarding how you are creating index using which client and how you are posting the same

Comment: You have created this request :  CreateIndexRequest request. But where are you passing it to es client to execute the same ?

Comment: @aka_GK You need to use ElasticSearch resthighlevelclient to post a document and create index.

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed

Comment: Glad to know . Can you upvote the answer as well. Thanks

Comment: I tried.. but I don't have sufficient reputation, Sorry :(